# How to print to console from COM library summoned with Activator from .NET code?

Tags: c++, .net, com, comobject

There is COM object dll registered with regsvr32 in system which is doing some `foo()`

But how can I printf from it? e.g. I can't see anything if I just `printf("test");` from it.

I'm getting my com object by progid

```
let A<'T> progid =
    Activator.CreateInstance
        ( Type.GetTypeFromProgID progid )
            :?> 'T
```

and call method alike `myObj.foo()`

Comment: I'd implement and pass a custom C# interface to `foo`, e.h. `foo(IConsole console)`. `IConsole` would wrap the .NET `Console` object.

Comment: @Noseratio thank for suggestion but I need it just for testing so I stick with `ATLTRACE` and solution provided with @voodooattack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) first to bring up a console window in your GUI application.

Note that if you do this, add the following lines after the `AllocConsole` call.

```
freopen ("CONOUT$", "w", stdout );
freopen ("CONERR$", "w", stderr );
```

Also, you can redirect stdout/stderr to a file by doing this:

```
C:\> myprogram.exe > out.txt 2> err.txt
```

Comment: I've got console application

Comment: Did you try the second option?

Comment: Try adding this line to the COM object's entry point: `freopen ("CONOUT$", "w", stdout );`

Comment: Did you put that line before or after `AllocConsole`?

Comment: well it works if I run my app from command line but not if I run it from visual studio

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46221/discussion-between-voodooattack-and-heather)